# Reading XML tags in java, code optimization

Tags: java, optimization

What I am actually doing is a recursive function which reads the tags in the xml.  Below is the code:

```
private void readTag(org.w3c.dom.Node item, String histoTags, String fileName, Hashtable<String, String> tagsInfos) {
    try {
        if (item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            NodeList itemChilds = item.getChildNodes();

            for (int i=0; i < itemChilds.getLength(); i++) {
                org.w3c.dom.Node itemChild = itemChilds.item(i);
                readTag(itemChild, histoTags + "|" + item.getNodeName(), fileName, tagsInfos);
            }
      }
       else if (item.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
           tagsInfosSoft.put(histoTags, item.getNodeValue());
      }
}
```

This function takes some time to execute.  The xml the function reads is in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
     <Mouvement>
       <Com>
          <IdCom>32R01000000772669473</IdCom>
          <RefCde>32R</RefCde>
          <Edit>0</Edit>
       <Com>
     <Mouvement>
<Document>
```

Is there any way of optimizing this code in java?

Comment: You could use some xml-object mapping (for example using xstream) to do the job, that **might** be more efficient. Maybe you could post a mcve reproducing the "slowness"?

Comment: @RC.:  Can you please give an example?

Comment: see http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Two optimizations, don't know how much they will help:

- Don't use `getChildNodes()`. Use `getFirstChild()` and `getNextSibling()`.
- Reuse a single `StringBuilder` instead of creating a new one for every element (implicitly done by `histoTags + "|" + item.getNodeName()`).

But, you should also be aware that the text content of an element node may seen as a combination of multiple TEXT and CDATA nodes.

Your code will also work better if it works on elements, not nodes.

```
private static void readTag(Element elem, StringBuilder histoTags, String fileName, Hashtable<String, String> tagsInfos) {
    int histoLen = histoTags.length();
    CharSequence textContent = null;
    boolean hasChildElement = false;
    for (Node child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling()) {
        switch (child.getNodeType()) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                histoTags.append('|').append(child.getNodeName());
                readTag((Element)child, histoTags, fileName, tagsInfos);
                histoTags.setLength(histoLen);
                hasChildElement = true;
                break;
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
                //uncomment to test: System.out.println(histoTags + ": \"" + child.getTextContent() + "\"");
                if (textContent == null)
                    // Optimization: Don't copy to a StringBuilder if only one text node will be found 
                    textContent = child.getTextContent();
                else if (textContent instanceof StringBuilder)
                    // Ok, now we need a StringBuilder to collect text from multiple nodes
                    ((StringBuilder)textContent).append(child.getTextContent());
                else
                    // And we keep collecting text from multiple nodes
                    textContent = new StringBuilder(textContent).append(child.getTextContent());
                break;
            default:
                // ignore all others
        }
    }
    if (textContent != null) {
        String text = textContent.toString();
        // Suppress pure whitespace content on elements with child elements, i.e. structural whitespace
        if (! hasChildElement || ! text.trim().isEmpty())
            tagsInfos.put(histoTags.toString(), text);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
String xml = "<root>\n" +
             "  <tag>hello <![CDATA[world]]> Foo <!-- comment --> Bar</tag>\n" +
             "</root>\n";
Element docElem = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                                        .newDocumentBuilder()
                                        .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)))
                                        .getDocumentElement();
Hashtable<String, String> tagsInfos = new Hashtable<>();
readTag(docElem, new StringBuilder(docElem.getNodeName()), "fileName", tagsInfos);
System.out.println(tagsInfos);
```

**Output** (with print uncommented)

```
root: "
  "
root|tag: "hello "
root|tag: "world"
root|tag: " Foo "
root|tag: " Bar"
root: "
"
{root|tag=hello world Foo  Bar}
```

See how splitting the text inside the `<tag>` node using CDATA and comments caused the DOM node to contain multiple TEXT/CDATA child nodes.